# How to get Field value in User Defined Java Class in kettle?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to get the `Link` field in the `User Defined Java Class` step from my below transformation.
[image]

Here is the code which I have written in `User Defined Java Class`:

```
private String link;
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    Object[] r=getRow();
    if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    if (first) {
        link = getParameter("Link");
        first = false;
    }

    String linkField = get(Fields.In, link).getString(r);
    logBasic("link:" + link);


    return true;

}
```

When I run the above code, here is the error that I get at the User Defined Java Class Step:

```
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 - ERROR (version 5.4.0.1-130, build 1 from 2015-06-14_12-34-55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepException: 
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Unable to find In field helper for field name 'null'
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 - 
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.TransformClassBase.get(TransformClassBase.java:628)
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 -   at Processor.processRow(Processor.java:15)
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.userdefinedjavaclass.UserDefinedJavaClass.processRow(UserDefinedJavaClass.java:1018)
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016/06/28 11:26:57 - User Defined Java Class.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)
```

To confirm the fields, here is the snapshot of Preview Data till the `Filter rows` step:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out where I was missing. In the `User Defined Java Class`, in the Parameters tab below, I need to explicitly define the field name and it's alias, such as: [image]